# Using CriteriaQuery for Two different tables without any relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to use CriteriaQuery for two different table without having any relationship between them? I manage to use CriteriaQuery for two tables having a relationship(one to one, one to many).

If There is no relationship between table, I know I can achieve the same stuff using join in the handwritten query. But I want to know if it can be possible with CriteriaQuery as an efficient way.

Note: I searched the SO but didn't get the answer properly.

Thanks in advance.